# What is the network solution for Kubernetes in docker for Windows?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-windows, docker

Kubernetes has many networking solutions (flannel, calico, contrail).
I'm using Kubernetes installed from docker-for-windows and I cannot figure out what networking solution is applied out of the box.

Can anyone please point me out to how to find this?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box is a work in progress as of this writing, you'll have to configure your own. For example ToR (Top of the rack). The solutions are described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/#networking).

Basically, this (quoted from the docs):

1. Upstream L3 Routing - IP routes configured in upstream ToR
2. Host-Gateway - IP routes configured on each host
3. Open vSwitch (OVS) & Open Virtual Network (OVN) with Overlay -
   overlay networks (supports STT and Geneve tunneling types)
4. [Future - In Review] Overlay - VXLAN or IP-in-IP encapsulation using
   Flannel
5. [Future] Layer-3 Routing with BGP (Calico)

Comment: Thanks! I thought a network solution was always required, but from your comments I take that it is not, right?

Comment: It's required, but it's just not included out of the box.